# How can I determine if Organization Administration is enabled for my DocuSign account?

Tags: docusignapi

How to find if an Organization Administration is enabled for a DocuSign account? I would like to know if it is possible to proactively grant consent for some or all of the users in your account.

Alternate way to provide consent to an user to avoid redirecting to the consent page

Answer (score 0):

You can set your account to have an organization by following this article - https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=tku1629136038406&topicId=nkj1583359134234.html&_LANG=enus

To find out if your account has an organization or not, you can use the following endpoint of the DocuSign Monitor API:

```
GET /Management/v2/organizations
```

[organization:getOrganizations](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/organization/organization/getorganizations/) which returns a list of organizations that the user is a member of. The list will be empty if you don't have any organization set.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to provide consent to individual users within a DocuSign account to avoid redirecting to the consent page?

Comment: Consent is only required once per user/IK. So, they have to do it once at least if you use their userId. 
You could just use a system user for all API calls and then they won't even have to log in at all.

Comment: Thank you! we are using individual users with admin access configured in  the DocuSign account.  Is there a way to convert or create a new system user within the DocuSign account profile?

Comment: You can create a new system user from the "Settings" menu (eSignature Admin) and click on "User" on the left nav. I would suggest using an email address that is not associated with a person (like systemuser@company.com)